# how to remove only one item "-- select year --" from dropdown on item selection change?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I bind a dropdown in mvc application with "-- select year --" as a First element, On selection  a item from dropdown I want to delete "-- select year --" item from the drop down. How to achieve this?

Below code delete all items from dropdown...what need to make change here,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Year').change(function () {
            var yearsSelect = $('#Year');
            debugger;
            yearsSelect.empty();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('option:first', yearsSelect).remove();
```

or if you want to remove the one with an empty value (which is what the `DropDownListFor` helper uses for the default value):

```
$('option[value=""]', yearsSelect).remove();
```

Comment: second is definetly the way to go. Otherwise, each time it selects a year the first year will disappear